# How to add image in a React component from local path in img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

I am using the below img tag in my React component but the image is not displaying when I am taking the image source from a local path.

```
<img class="masthead-avatar mb-5" src="public/css/avataaars.svg" alt="..." />
```

Comment: What happens if you prefix a slash to the pathname: `/public/css/avataaars.svg`?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working

Answer (score 1):

why you are not trying this

```
import image from "./public/css/avataaars.svg"

<img src={image} alt="image" />
```

or if you want to use svg as a component you can try

```
import {ReactComponent as SvgIcon} from "./public/css/avataaars.svg"

<SvgIcon/>
```

Comment: ERROR in ./src/Masterhead.js 6:0-46
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /public/css/avataaars.svg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

webpack compiled with 1 error but even after adding it to src folder it is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can try this -:

using require ...

```
<img src={require(`public/css/avataaars.svg`)} alt="" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working